# node js npm package OSX fails

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js

After reading many ( if not all :-| ) posts having similar problems, I still don't have a working local (or a "global") install of node.js's *[Mac OSX system tools](http://npmjs.org/package/osx)*.  Showing global attempt here...

Their doc implies either an npm install ***or*** a build from source  - but not npm THEN source. However, a test run seems to be requiring compiled file(s) that don't exist after the attempted install.

Details:

It's my understanding that npm should be sufficient, but when I do the recommended

```
sudo npm install -g osx
```

npm creates /usr/local/lib/node_modules and populates with

```
README.md  osx.cc   osx.js  package.json    wscript
```

Running (from anywhere) node theirSample.js, containing:

```
Var osx = require('osx');
// also tried full path as recommended in other answers
var osx = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/osx');
```

The error is the commonly seen "**cannot find module**".  However, the specific error is:

```
Cannot find module './build/Release/osx'
```

Which stems from the above **osx.js** created in /usr/local/lib/node_modules
That file has the errant line:

```
var osx = require('./build/Release/osx');
```

That implies that I need the ./build/Release/osx dir, but npm did not create this under the modules dir.  So does that mean I need to compile the source?  If so, any pointers on set up please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to install it globally, and second, this module is already 2 years old, and it was tested on Darwin 11.2.
It does not work with OS X "Mavericks" - just tested on my machine.

As a replacement, I would recommend to take a look at [os build-in module](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_os), which provides basic operating-system related utility functions, and is OS-agnostic

Comment: Thx Andrei +1 - I didn't notice how old that thing was! Will try your suggestion.  Global was a (wrong :) attempt at getting it working.